# twitter bootstrap using tooltip to comply with html5

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i was using tooltip and it is working perfectly, but it seems like my html was not validated properly due to the rel='tooltip' not being a correct value.

so, I changed my code as following

```
<a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="under construction" class="line-through tooltip-flag">Blog</a>
```

and my javascript as following

```
$("a[data-tooltip=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

but that did not work and when i tried to force it $("a[data-tooltip=tooltip]").tooltip('show'); i got a js error. so, I assumed the tooltip.js requires to see the rel='tooltip' field. so, I replaced it with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize all tooltips
    $("[data-tooltip=tooltip]").attr('rel', 'tooltip');
    $("[data-tooltip=tooltip]").queue(function(){
        $("a[data-tooltip=tooltip]").tooltip();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });

});
```

but still am not able to get the tooltip to work, any ideas?

UPDATE:
below is the JS error am getting

```
data[option] is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
```

Comment: `rel="tooltip"` doesn't have any meaning for bootstrap tooltip anyway. See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js What would helpful is posting the JS error you get.

Comment: hi @Esailija i just updated my post with the js error hope it will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because you are overriding the internal instance data of bootstrap tooltip. Using anything else should work:

`data-my-tooltip="something"`

**Do not use:**

`data-tooltip="something"`

This said, you do not need the `data` or `rel` at all. You could simply give the links a class `class="this-is-a-tooltip"` and then call `$(".this-is-a-tooltip").tooltip()`

Comment: What does that line in bootstrap do exactly and what's the long form of the syntax?  Best guess is it's just setting the data from the 'options' string provided as a param, but these days, I wouldn't be surprised if it was alien code for mind control.  I guess that makes me gullible.